# AVERAGEIFS errors when filtering on two criteria from 2 different columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is the logical problem I am trying unsuccessfully to produce an answer for, stated in English:
"Average all numbers in column G (refers to the relevant worksheet, which is in table format) where the value is greater than zero and where the value in the corresponding column K for that cell is greater than a minimum threshold specified by a designated cell (B3 in this case)."

I have tried this three different ways:

```
 =AVERAGEIFS(gamedata17!$G:$G, gamedata17!$K:$K, ">" & B3, gamedata17!$G:$G, ">0")
```

(YIELDS “DIV/0”)

```
 =IF(AND(gamedata17!$G:$G >0, gamedata17!$K:$K>B3), AVERAGE(gamedata17!$G:$G))
```

YIELDS ("FALSE")

and last but not least . . .

```
 =IF(gamedata17!$K:$K, ">" & B3, AVERAGEIFS(gamedata17!$G:$G, gamedata17!$G:$G, ">0"))
```

Which Yields "SPILL".

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but just to confirm, B3 in this case is an integer (700), column K in the relevant table is the correct reference, and includes figures greater than 700, column G in the table is the correct reference and includes multiple values that are greater than zero, and the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(gamedata19!K:K, ">" & B3, gamedata19!G:G, ">0")
```

Yields the answer 6, so AVERAGEIFS (or an alternative formulation) should be able to produce an average for those 6 cells.

Comment: Your first formula is correct.  If it is returning `DIV/0`, there's a problem with your data.  I note that your last formula refers to `gamedata19`, and your other formulas refer to `gamedata17`.  Are you sure you have the correct sheet references in your first formula?

Comment: This error returns when dividing by 0 or an empty cell,, so just check the data you are using with,, or better share sample data with us,, to fix the issue.  Once try by add this to formula `gamedata17!$G:$G, "<>"""`

Comment: Check `Col K` ,, I'm sure has many empty Cells !!

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks--yes, the dreaded typo killed it there with the 19 instead of 17!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Let me explain that why you are getting error:*

**Reason behind `#DIV/0` error:**

- Any of these parts of the formula, `gamedata17!$G:$G, ">0"` or `gamedata17!$K:$K, ">" & B3` , either encounter with *blank cells or Zeros*.

**Reason behind errors with 2nd and 3rd formula:**

- Primarily, both must be an array (CSE) formula and need to finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Other is, `gamedata17!$G:$G, ">0"` or  `gamedata17!$K:$K, ">" & B3` encounters with either *blank/blanks or Zero* even.

  **But the most probable reason behind the errors, with all 3 formulas is, *values in Col K are smaller then `B3`.***

Also, formula 3 needs little correction and it should be like,

```
{=IF(gamedata17!$K:$K> B3, AVERAGEIFS(gamedata17!$G:$G, gamedata17!$G:$G, ">0"))}
```

- Replace `=IF(gamedata17!$K:$K, ">" & B3` with
  `=IF(gamedata17!$K:$K>B3`

*Otherwise you get Average value presided with `>` sign.*

Comment: Rajesh, thank you for the thorough answer.  I have two questions, if you don't mind.  First, I am confused about when I should and should not be using quotations around evaluations. When should I be using ">0" and when is it just >0?  Second, how would I attack this problem if I was seeking to do it with MEDIAN, which does not have an IFS version?  So, the question in that case would be "What is the median of values in $G$G (a) $K$K is within our threshold, and the $G$G value is greater than zero?

Comment: @janalytics,, glad to help you,, with few Excel functions like `Countif,, Countifs, Sumif & Sumifs` ">0" is allowed but with IF it doesn't. You may use an array formula like `{=MEDIAN(IF(A1:A7>0,B1:B7,""))}` .